# Create and run append queries for multiple linked tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, linked-tables

I am trying to write a VBA code in Microsoft Access that will create and run 60 queries to select new records from 60 linked tables and insert them into 60 tables of the same format. Some background may help here:

I have a large database (lets call the original database "A") that will eventually have over 60 tables, 60 forms & 60 reports. When one of our workers goes out into the field and doesn't have an internet connection, they are going to create new records on a copy of the database stored on their desktop (lets call the duplicate database "B"). Once they have an internet connection, I want them to be able to press a button on either database (I have been trying to code the macro on database A because I thought that would be easiest) and have the new records they created on database B inserted into database A.

I have found [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670716/how-to-merge-data-from-two-separate-access-2007-databases) online that seems to be just what I need but when I try to run the macro it gives Error 3022, which says:

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship

I have tried running this macro with both databases on my desktop with only 1 linked table with a primary key that is an autonumber, I tried running it with a random autonumber, I tried not having any primary key or index or autonumber and even no records at all. I even tried running it without any linked tables. All ways of trying give me the same Error 3022. I really don't want to create 60 queries one by one so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you wizards in advance :)

Here is the code I have tried:

```
Public Sub ImportTableData(ByVal pstrTable As String, ByVal pstrDb As String)

    Dim strSql As String
    
    strSql = "INSERT INTO " & pstrTable & vbNewLine & _
        "SELECT *" & vbNewLine & _
        "FROM " & pstrTable & " IN '" & pstrDb & "';"

    CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    
End Sub

Public Sub ImportAllTables()
    Const cstrDb As String = "C:\MyPath\DatabaseB.accdb"
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        'ignore system and temporary tables '
        If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
            Call ImportTableData(tdf.Name, cstrDb)
        End If
    Next tdf

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 3078
        strMsg = "Input table " & tdf.Name & " not found."
        MsgBox strMsg
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure ImportAllTables"
        MsgBox strMsg
        GoTo ExitHere
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

When I remove the piece of code: 'dbFailOnError', I get different errors. First thing that pops up when I run the macro is: ''Input table 'LocalTableName' not found'', which is the table I am trying to add the records to. Once I click 'Ok' on that pop up box, that is when Error 3134 pops up which says 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement'. I am assuming Error 3134 only pops up because it cannot find the local input table (the fist pop up box).

Also, I tried changing the line of code that says: 'Const cstrDb As String = ''C:\MyPath\DatabaseB.accdb''' to instead point to database A (which is the one I am coding the macro on) like this: 'Const cstrDb As String = ''C:\MyPath\DatabaseA.accdb'''. This doesn't give me the first pop up that says ''Input table 'LocalTableName' not found'' but it still gives Error 3134.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong and have spent over 20 hours on this problem trying dozens of different things. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS access insert into without duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393494/ms-access-insert-into-without-duplicate)

Comment: as we kno nothing about your tables and which columsn make the primary key, that produces the error, you can see in the duplicate how you would eliminate doubles, ou need to adept it so that that the join find all doubles

Comment: That link is similar to what I am trying to do but I want queries to be created for all 60 linked tables. I tried running this code with only one linked table that didnt have any records in database A and a few records in database B. I tried multiple things with the primary key that I explained in my original question. I just tried removing the end of the first sub that said "dbFailOnError" and this gave me a different result. When I tried to run the macro again, it said "Input table 'LinkedTableName' not found" & after it says "Error 3134 Syntax error in Insert Into statement"

Comment: Originally yes HansUp. I tried setting the autonumber to random and even changing it to just a number on both tables. Nothing worked. Seems like the query finds the name of the linked table but when it tries to run, access cant find the linked table. Strange problem

Comment: The sql that throws the 3134 error is the same code from the vba code in my original question, the strSql. The destination table is local and I am trying to select data from the linked table. There is a JobID field that is the primary key and an autonumber that is currently set to have new values be random, and a JobNumber that is just a number. Both of these fields are indexed. There are currently no relationships but I will probably have to make some in the future. And the source table that is listed after FROM should be the linked table but Im not sure if the code is doing that correctly.

Comment: Also, the only reason why I got different error messages was because I removed the part of the code that said "dbFailOnError". Thank you for your attention and trying to help HansUp :)

Comment: I just realized I made an error in the comment from a few hours ago, I said that the error that comes up before Error 3134 says "Input table 'LinkedTableName' not found" when it is actually saying "Input table 'LocalTableName' not found", which is the table I am trying to add the records to. My apologies for the mix up. Once I click "Ok" on that pop up box, that is when Error 3134 pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main issue is how you going to ensure that the PK (primary keys) and FK (foreign keys) remain the same when they go out to the field and start entering data?

There is a good chance that PK/FK values will now be duplicated, or be the same for on one of the field users.

If a user out in the field adds a record, and someone at main work location adds record, they now are to very likly have the same PK value.

I suppose this might work if you use random autonumbers (never even knew that was a option after all these years!!!) - but I can't say even that going to be 100% reliable.

And when you import that copy from the out in the field user, then either:

You always ensure you accept  and take the same PK value, or you let access generate a new PK - but if you do that, then the child records FK value would have to be updated then.

You not really try to do a simple import, but are attempting to do a database synchronization- a stunning and VERY advanced concept. And a very challenging problem.

Access (mdb format) did at one time support what is called database replication. This feature would be ideal for your setup.

However, but for newer accDB formats, it not supported anymore. (and quite sure by around access 2010, replication support was dropped anyway).

So, you could try random for the autonumber. I mean, you simple cannot have the PK's being duplicated on each computer - plain and simple.

The other possbile?

You add to each and every table that has a PK, and add a new column called PKF (f for in the field).

And for every table that has a FK, you add a new column called FKF (again, add F to this).

So, in the field, your PK/FK used is NOT the same as the main master database at work.

So, I wrote a Android sync routine based on above. The applcation was Access, but I moved the data to sql server (but same idea). I moved to sql server since my android phone could use its local database (sqlLite) and hit sql server. (but, it would be difficult to get android to hit some server and read + use a accDB file - but was easy to have Android phone hit the sql server database directly).

Gee, maybe they could use Android phones!!! but, this would assume  you up to speed writing android software, 100% conformable with SQL server, and also access. I was lucky, had all 3 skill sets, so that is the road and hammer I choose.

And speaking of above?
Maybe your lucky, and you have sql server running at work (not express edition, but full edition). I suggest this considering, since the free edition of SQL express can be what we call a replication subscriber to a main sql database. This allows you to sync your local database with the main mothership database.

So, adopting free SQL server express on each field laptop could be a possible solution. Then when they get to a working network, they sync the database using replication.

But, you could try and roll your own sync system.

I did that for an android applcation I wrote, and for a desktop Access application I had. (but, to make all the moving parts easy, I did adopt sql server for database - continued to use Access as the application/UI part).

Now, using "random" for the PK looks to be a possible solution. I just don't know how random, and if this choice can reliable avoid PK collisions for autonumbers.

Random seems like the best road - but ONLY if that choice would prevent duplicate PK id's being used out in the field for new records.

## Edit: Random - not even close - it not random enough

So, a bit of research - no, random PK will not work, you still often wind up with collisions - so that idea is off the table.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, gave me a lot to consider. The way you described the sql server made it seem like my best option. Honestly I don't have any experience in coding or servers. I just started this job a few months ago and since then I have only coded vba in excel and access. Usually I start with code I find online and I make adjustments where I need to. So far things have worked out and my boss has given me the opportunity to create this database that will be used by our testing division. It will be a VERY big piece of the companys operations. I would like it to be perfect

Comment: So with my lack of experience & the big undertaking I have been assigned in mind, do you have any recommendations on where I should start to build a sql server? It would need to be extremely secure and user friendly for the guys who aren't tech savvy. Thank you again for your initial response, I really appreciate the detail you put into it

Comment: Well, SQL server is like Access - easy, but only after you spend some time with it. SQL express is free, and in fact I used it so much, that most of my Access applications now use SQL server for the database. But, from Access side, and skill set? Everything works the same in Access - you just using linked tables to sql server in place of a Access back end. However, random numbers is OFF the table. So, either you build a sync system, or spend the time to learn SQL server, and then sql replication. But, as noted, while each laptop can use free SQL server, the main one at work is not free.

Comment: Database replication and synchronization is perhaps one of the most advanced database topics you will ever work with. In fact, it is one of the advanced areas of computing science in general. However, there are solutions you can adopt that can work quite well, and they will require a min of changes to existing code.

Comment: Thank you very much Albert. I am going to work on the SQL server today and tomorrow. I will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Well, install SQL express on your computer. (and of course SSMS = sql server management studio). You can also do a data migration (migrate the access data to sql server. For that you need to get the Access migration assistsnt for SQL server (again a free download). However, do you have a full version of SQL server running at work? While I stated SQL express is free, 100% much the same as paid version, it does not support being a replication master. (only a subscriber to sql server paid version). However, you could as noted build  your own sync system - it not out of the question.

Comment: And before you migrate to sql server, have you worked with a split Access system? (application part, and then linked tables to back end accDB file?).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will get to downloading :). I have worked with a split access database before. I built it myself and split the front and back end before releasing it to other employees.

Comment: Ok, so adopting sql server is much better here, even if you don't use sql replication. This topic is a bit much for SO.  The next problem would be to limit scope. So, in the field, edits of current data, and say adding new data. (but say not support for deletes). The other issue, can you keep the Front end the same for the field deployments. (you don't want to have to maintain two versions of the applcation. You probably can. So, then next step and big question is do  you roll your own sync code, or use data replication. And how many tables are related - that gives idea of how complex problem

Comment: Yea that is a lot to take in. I am not sure what you mean by your fourth sentence that begins with 'So,'. Do you mind clarifying that for me? I promise this will be the last stupid question I ask lol

Comment: No worries! Question/issue was do you want to roll your own kind of sync code (not a huge deal - quite much what you were attempting to do anyway, right???).  As I stated, while SQL express is free, great for access - use it all the time. And great for those field laptops? The problem is SQL server replication is not really free cost, since you need a full paid version to be the "master" to the subscriber databases. That can be quite expensive. So, often, if we can limit the scope of what data is to be synced, by reducing the requirements, then it becomes well possible to roll own sync code.

Comment: So, you can well develop your own sync design. It not a huge amount of code. We can reduce efforts say if field users don't need to delete rows of data. However, since we going to use SQL server, then writing and rolling your own sync code becomes within reach. So, we need all tables to have a LastUpdated column (date/time). We still also need to deal (or eliminate) the issue of PK's being the same when field computers add new records. There are as many ways to do this there are flavors of ice cream. Given 60 tables, then how many tables are related would decide this issue and road .

Comment: Awesome thank you very much Albert. You gave me a great place to start. You're awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally. Basically I changed the line of code that executes the SQL to debug.print. This showed me what was going on. The problem is I had linked the tables from the other database when they didn't need to be linked. The names of the local tables would be 'Table A' & the linked tables were 'Table A1'. So there would be a query generated for 'Table A' and another query generated for 'Table A1'. Since there are no tables by the name 'Table A1' in Database B, the query wouldn't work. Plus the fact that, in the line of code executing the SQL, there was an option that says 'dbFailOnError' so since half of the queries weren't working, this option rolls back any updates made by the queries that did work.

I removed all of the linked tables and the macro runs perfectly, unless there are records that are the same on both databases. If I remove 'dbFailOnError' from the code, then the macro runs well no matter what.

So the macro is doing what I want it to but I would like to keep the 'dbFailOnError' part of the code so I will have to do 2 things. First, I have to solve the problem with the primary keys. The answer on this thread by Albert describes this problem well. Second, I have to adjust the SQL to be able to only select records that don't already exist in Database A. I am assuming I can do this by adding a WHERE to the end of the SQL.
I will make an update once I fix these problems, or if I just run an SQL server instead.
Thank you everyone for your help :)